# Data analysis on process timestamp data to find bottlenecks and patterns

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-mining, data-analysis

I have a timestamp data for a a process. Each timestamp in a data point represents the time when a certain subprocess begins.
Kindly suggect how data-mining could be applied yo this dataset to identify bottlenecks and patterns in the data.

Comment: Hi @Anir, I think your question is too broad. You should look at resources online for timeseries analysis. There are several good articles on the topic. Once you try one of these and face a specific problem, you should come back and post to stackoverflow.

Comment: Try to plot the data, in 1d, 2d, 3d. Make some good guesses where patterns could form. This usually gives a first insight on how to do a detailed analysis (e.g. Fourier, machine learning, max, min, average, autocorrelations, patterns)